# DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED doesn't occurs

Tags: android, drag-and-drop

I'm working with [Drag and Drop](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/drag-drop.html), everythings is OK, but, let consider this scene: i have a `LinearLayout` is parent view, and it have one child view is `ImageView`. `LinearLayout` is listen for [`OnDragListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnDragListener.html), and `ImageView` is dragedView. So, when i drag the `ImageView`, the `DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED` doesn't occurs, and then `DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED` doesn't occurs too.

Mean while, the other actions are working as expected.

P/s: When working, there is one problem when i drag my `ImageView` (inside my `LinearLayout`) out side of my `LinearLayout` and drop it, so, my `ImageView` is disappear and there is no event is invoked. I want to detect this case to bring my `ImageView` turn back to it's original position.

Can anybody give me a suggestion?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

accordding to the implementation of ViewGroup.dispatchDragEvent(), ViewGroup does not handle STARTED ENDED if any child has handled the event.

```
public boolean dispatchDragEvent(DragEvent event) {

    .... // dispatch event to children

    // If none of our children could handle the event, try here
    if (!retval) {
        // Call up to the View implementation that dispatches to installed listeners
        retval = super.dispatchDragEvent(event);
    }
}
```